# SAS Rows into Columns

Tags: sas

I need to convert rows into columns in SAS. My question is almost identical to this one:
[Convert Database Rows into Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946234/convert-database-rows-into-columns)

The main difference is that I need to use arrays to do so. I am not entirely sure how to approach this. I have looked at TRANSPOSE, but that doesn't really fit my question's criteria. Would appreciate any advice on how to start this question, or how to approach it.

Thanks.

Edit:

```
Data old;
input id year cost; 
datalines;
1 1998 20
1 1999 30
1 2000 40
2 1998 20
2 1999 21
2 2000 25
3 1998 32
3 1999 33
;
run; 

data want;
set old;
by ID;
array allcost(3) c1 - c3;
retain c1-c3;
if first.id then i=1;
else i+1;
allcost(3) = cost;
if last.id;
run;
```

What I want this to look like:

```
       1998 1999 2000

1      20    30   40
2      20    21   25
3      32    33
```

Instead of getting this result, I get a list of cost in the c3 column. What am I doing wrong?
Note that c1-c3 represent the years.

Comment: For rotating a table, [`PROC TRANSPOSE`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/70377/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1r2tjnp8ewe3sn1acnpnrs3xbad.htm) does answer the question.

You are talking about arrays, but you have not told us why yet. Most likely, you will want to have a look at [`PROC TABULATE`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/basess/68381/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1k5pgl78tt14pn19adlvtvyw8l1.htm).

Comment: Thanks, I'm not too sure where I need to use the arrays to achieve that result, as the question I need to answer doesn't specify, hence the confusion.

Comment: Please post some sample data, and an example of the output dataset you're trying to produce, both typed out as text within your question,  and perhaps that will make it clearer whether proc transpose is appropriate?

Comment: If you must use arrays, then search on this site for "sas transpose arrays" for some answers (there are plenty).  As well as posting some example data, you should also show what code you've attempted.

Comment: Please show some data.

Comment: Thanks Longfish, it's amazing what you can find with the right search! Will add data if I get stuck in my attempt, just needed a pointer in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to use arrays?  Is this homework?  If so you still need to write a well specified question.

Comment: Okay, I have looked into it and tried something out, but am not getting the result I need. I have edited the question with my attempt

Comment: Based on the data you've provided this is a perfect situation for `proc transpose`. Try and run it with `id` as your `by` variable, and `year` as your `id` variable.

Comment: The question requires me to use arrays, instead of transpose. Unless I can do both? Will try it out now, thanks.

Comment: This is EXACTLY your question here: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/modules/reshaping-data-long-to-wide-using-the-data-step/

Comment: And similarly for PROC TRANSPOSE long to wide - https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/modules/how-to-reshape-data-long-to-wide-using-proc-transpose/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have the right idea but your only getting values in the `c3` column because the statement `allcost(3)` is only pointing to the third position in the array so you need to use the value of `i` as an index.

Let's make a small modification to your code and see what happens.

```
data new;
set old;
by id;
retain _1998-_2000(drop=year cost i);
array costs(3) _1998-_2000;
if first.id then i = 1;
else i + 1;
costs(i) = cost;         * Adding the 'i' index will point to the correct cost variable.;
if last.id then output;  * This will output the array as a row.;
run;
```

This code seems to get pretty close but let's check the ouput.

```
id    _1998    _1999    _2000

 1      20       30       40
 2      20       21       25
 3      32       33       25
```

Everything looks right here *except* for the third row for `_2000`. This is because the value for `_2000` was never replaced in the last by-group. To fix this we can clear out the array at the beginning of each by-group.

```
data new(drop=year cost i j);
set old;
by id;
retain _1998-_2000;
array costs(3) _1998-_2000;
if first.id then do;
    do j = 1 to 3;
        costs(j) = .; * set each value in array to missing.;
    end;
    i = 1;
end;
else i + 1;
costs(i) = cost;
if last.id then output;
run;
```

Now the resulting dataset looks correct.

```
id    _1998    _1999    _2000

 1      20       30       40
 2      20       21       25
 3      32       33        .
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @J_Lard excellent answer - I wish there was a way to favorite answers. Wonder why isn't there...