# Combine multiple results into a single string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to combine multiple results into a single string in SQL Server?

I have the following table:

```
NameID Name
------ -----
1      Alvin
2      Alan
3      Ben
4      Tom
```

How can I select the table and return the select result as below:

```
Group
-----
Alvin, Alan, Ben and Tom
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Database Rows into Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946234/convert-database-rows-into-columns)

Comment: telling us your rdbms would be helpful. in oracle it is listagg in sql server you  can do it with xml path, in mysql it is group_concat

Comment: Always helpful to add a tag for the particular verrsion of SQL Server you are using. T-SQL is evolving with each version, and it's possible that certain versions have different solutions to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  SELECT
  SUBSTRING((SELECT
    ',' + CAST(Name AS varchar)
  FROM table_name
  FOR xml PATH (''))
  , 2, 10000) AS Group1
```

[image]

Comment: `Name` will be truncated to 30 characters due to missing length `cast`. Also what if the name list is greater than 10000 characters

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server 2017 introduced the [`STRING_AGG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to simplify this process:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(Name,', ') FROM Table
```

This will return:

```
Alvin, Alan, Ben, Tom
```

There is a good summary on these concepts here as well: [SQL Server: Concatenate Multiple Rows Into Single String](https://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/sql-server/concatenate-multiple-rows-into-single-string)

> If it is absolutely necessary to inject the *and* in the end, then we could use a *[replace last instance of](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48316722/1690217)* routine:
> ***NOTE:** this level of formatting is much better managed in the rendering logic, not the SQL data logic.*
>
> ```
> SELECT STUFF(names,LastIndex,2,' and ') 
> FROM (
>     SELECT STRING_AGG(Name,', ') names  
>     FROM Table
> ) as raw
> CROSS APPLY (SELECT LEN(names)-CHARINDEX(' ,', REVERSE(names)) as LastIndex) as Helper
> ```
>
> Returns:
>
> ```
> Alvin, Alan, Ben and Tom
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using `FOR XML PATH`

```
SELECT Stuff((SELECT ', ' + NAME
              FROM  Yourtable
              FOR xml path(''), type).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')
```

`value` method helps us to avoid encoding of `xml` *reserved* characters in the result

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @a TABLE
(Col1   int,
 Col2   varchar(5)
);
--
DECLARE @b  VARCHAR(500) = '';
--
INSERT INTO @a (Col1, Col2)
VALUES  (1,'Alvin'),
        (2,'Alan'),
        (3,'Ben'),
        (4,'Tom');
--
SELECT @b = COALESCE(@b,'') + Col2 + ', '
FROM @a;
--
SELECT STUFF(STUFF(@b, LEN(@b), 1, ''), LEN(@b) + 1 - CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(STUFF(@b, LEN(@b), 1, ''))), 1, ' and')
```

Output:

Alvin, Alan, Ben and Tom